# Split and add specific charcters to a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with key-wording modules where each word end with `,` and remove spaces from the string example is given below:

if string is

```
one man sitting with girl ,  baby girl ,   Smiling girl
```

then result should be

```
,one man sitting with girl,baby girl,Smiling girl,
```

I am trying this

```
  string[] strArray = str15.Split(new char[] { ',', ';' });
        if (strArray.Length >= 1)
            {
                foreach (string str3 in strArray)
                {
                    if (str3 != string.Empty)
                    {
                        strr1 = strr1 + str3 + ",";

                    }
                }
            }
```

But not able to remove spaces from string.

Comment: Split -> Trim -> Join

Comment: Just `Split(',')` and `Trim()` each of these, then you can `Join` these

Comment: Do you need starting comma ?

Comment: Why `,`  is added in beginning?

Comment: are those commas at the beginning and end typo or you put them intentionally?

Comment: i have needed in first n last with `,`

Comment: Come on, WTF of downvote all of the answers? explain it...

Comment: @Mehdi Khademloo Downvote requires 125 rep. for your kind info.

Comment: My talking to @Downvoter , not you

Comment: The 2 downvotes were mine. I did it because I thought they deserved a downvote. That's my reason.

Comment: I also upvoted two answers by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is tokenise the string, using `Split()`.

```
string input = "some words   ,  not split , in a sensible    ,    way";   
string[] sections = input.Split(',');
```

This gives you an array of strings split by the comma delimiter, which would look something like this:

```
"some words   "
"  not split "
" in a sensible    "
"    way"
```

Now you want to trim those spaces off. The `string` class has a great little function called `Trim()` which removes all whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc) from the start and end of strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sections.Length; i++)
    sections[i] = sections[i].Trim();
```

Now you have an array with strings like this:

```
"some words"
"not split"
"in a sensible"
"way"
```

Next, you want to join them back together with a comma delimiter.

```
string result = string.Join(",", sections);
```

This gives you something along the lines of this:

```
"some words,not split,in a sensible,way"
```

And finally, you can add the commas at the start and end:

```
result = "," + result + ",";
```

Of course, this isn't the cleanest way of doing it. It's just an easy way of describing the individual steps. You can combine all of this together using LINQ extensions:

```
string result = "," + string.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim())) + ",";
```

This takes the input, splits it on the comma delimiter, then for each item in the list executes a lambda expression `s => s.Trim()`, which selects the trimmed version of the string for each element. This resulting enumerable is then passed back into `string.Join()`, and then we add the two commas at the start and end. It has the same function as the above steps, but does it one line.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their reasoning, so that I can fix any problems they noticed?

Comment: You can have +1 from me for not just being correct but fully explaining it.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful explanation @Polynomial , i really appreciated your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        string test = "one man sitting with girl ,  baby girl ,   Smiling girl";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s+,\s+");

        string result = regex.Replace(test, ",");
```

Comment: Seriously? Regex for this?

Comment: @Polynomial is there any problem?

Comment: Yeah, i would do that, because in this way you could be flexible if the requirements go harder...  Regex would still be my choice.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo Apart from missing the start and ending commas as per OPs request, it's also horribly inefficient to invoke a grammar compiler and perform pattern matching against a string, just to do something as trivial as split, trim, and join. This is not a pattern matching problem; it's about splitting strongly delimited data and processing the parts individually.

Comment: @Polynomial Inefficient yes, incorrect... no! But yeah, I would never use RegEx for this.

Comment: @DavidG As I pointed out, it is technically incorrect as it misses the starting and ending commas. But that's a trivial thing. I just disapprove of such solutions being touted as "the right way to do it". It teaches new developers bad habits.

Comment: @Polynomial Totally agree there. I would like to see a comment of that nature in the answer, then it may start to become worthy of an upvote (but not accept)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var input = "one man sitting with girl ,  baby girl ,   Smiling girl";

    var output = string.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()));

    output = string.Concat(",", output, ",");
```

Answer (score -1):

`Split` your string and join it again by removing the white-spaces:

```
var input = "one man sitting with girl ,  baby girl ,   Smiling girl";

var output = string.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()));

// If you wanna  enclose it with commas
output = string.Format(",{0},",output);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce ",one man sitting with girl,baby girl,Smiling girl,".

Comment: @brz It does if you add the missing `)` to the end (and the `,` prefix)

Comment: @DavidG and the missing `,` postfix. Yes, IF!

Comment: @brz I thought the commas were typo. even if they were not, it's not a hard thing to do anyway.